# My Blender 2.8 file is super slow to render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I'm still fairly new to Blender and I have a rendering issue.

I'm making this 4 minutes video featuring a long constant travelling of the camera through multiple environments.
One of those environment is a prison I made.

The scene includes lots of vertices, I guess, because of all those prison bars and railing.
Also, I've put a few lights for the ambiance.
All was going pretty well until I've duplicate the left part of my scene to make the right one.

As soon as it was done, I tried to display it in render mode and Blender crashed.
So I did a bit of cleaning and got rid of a few non-relevant vertices and the lights on my last floor.
After that, the render ability of Bender was back and I decided to render the prison part of the animation before going to bed.

The next morning, today, I woke up and immediately saw that the render was nowhere close to be done.
So I decided to cancel it, hoping it would let me see what he had exported so far.
Nope, can't do.

So I figure something was wrong and went looking on the web for answers.
And, yeah, there's those tutorials talking about samples and tiles and GPU's…
But as I was watching them, I realised that my scene is not that complicated.
Sure, there's a lot of bars and a few lights but it's nothing compare to that fireflighted tree in the night from the Blender site or even the first creature covered in fur coming.
Also, despite having restart my computer, Blender has now a real hard time rendering just one image from the scene (a me-forcing-Blender-to-quit-cause-it's-going-nowhere type of hard time).

Something is wrong.
Very wrong.
And I don't get what.

So I could try to tweak the parameters addressed in the tutorials but I feel it would not be as problem solving than me, understanding what's going on and what matters in a render.

I'm working on a MacBook pro (15-inch, 2018), 2.2 GHz Intel Core i7, 16 Go 2400 MHz DDR4, running on macOS Mojave (10.14.6).
For the Blender 2.8 file, I use the eevee rendering engine and here are the specs of my rendering :
[image: the spces, as they are now]

And here's some shots of my scene :
[image: material preview in viewport]
[image: render preview in viewport]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: First thing you always want to do is changing your output settings to render as an *image sequence*, preferably OpenEXR instead of FFmpeg (might be an encoding issue on osx). Then render **one image** of the sequence and see how long it takes to get a better estimation. If you'd like to get some kind of benchmark for your file, I'd suggest share a blend with us using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: "My Blender 2.8 file is super slow to render" - yeah, mine too. :D Welcome.

Comment: OK.
So, I did change my output settings to OpenEXR and, after that, to PNG.

Comment: sorry, I hit enter while writing my answer.
here's the rest :
The result is the same, unfortunately.

What I find to be the most strange is that Blender can display my scene in render view in the viewport with not that much effort.
But rendering 1 image is still quite impossible.
Much more impossible than before I started to try and render this part of animation.

About this benchmark thing, now.
I wasn't aware of this, looked it up and I'm not entirely sure of what it is.
Is it like some kind of doctoring of my file and computer and relationship between the two ?

Comment: I just did try to upload my file on the link you provided.
But it's, like, 50 Mb too heavy…

Comment: And, to answer your last question : I don't know if it renders.
It make my computer go really slow and I give up and quit Blender before anything happens. What I can say is that it's waaaay slower that yesterday, when the first signs of rendering happening were showing up before my patience went out.

Comment: Suggest to upload the file somewhere else, and keep in mind that your machine is quite low-end for serious 3d work.

Comment: Okay, I understand.
I gonna try to upload it somewhere and let you know.
Thank you very much.

Comment: ok, so, here it is :
https://transferxl.com/08LxX4J6FGw6b

If I can't go somewhere from here, do you think it's insane of me to continue working on my animation with the intention of finding a more "Blendery" computer to do the export ?
Thanks, anyway !

Comment: Also, I would like to add, because I think it may be relevant after all, that this specific project is NOT serious 3D work.
It's just something we're making while being lockdown.
The project is mixing PNG cutouts, 3D models, green screen in a 3D environment and is intended to be a visual mess.
I got caught up in the pleasure of doing CGI and so I decided to put peculiar effort in the making of the prison set.
So, to be clear and concise, I'll take the not-ideal-but-kinda-working-anyway solution over the one intended for (aspiring) pros, if such thing exists.
(the solution, not the pros.)

Comment: Go to *Render Properties > Shadows* and decrease 'Cube Size' as well as 'Cascade Size' to 1024 for that portion of the clip, then it will render. As assumed, it doesn't take "forever" blender *crashes* due to hardware limitations (graphics card).

Comment: Waw! That's it! And now that you mention it, I may have changed those values at one point around that same time to fix a problem I was not really having and feel quite like a dummy, right now. But thanks anyway, that's great !

Comment: How do I mention that my problem has been solved, btw ?